# Using a list with regex in php

Tags: php, regex

```
$word = file('list.txt');
$content = file_get_contents('fleetyfleet.txt');
```

fleetyfleet.txt contains

> DimensionNameGreenrandomjunktextextcstuffidonwantDimensionNameBluemoreeecrapidontwannaseeeDimensionNameYellowDimensionNameGrayrandomcrapDimensionNameRed

list.txt contains

> Green Blue Yellow

what i want is to be able to find DimensionName then store the word after it into an array if the word is in list.txt

so when script was ran the result stored in array would be Green,Blue,Yellow but not Red and Gray because they are not in our list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to `explode()` your file contents by delimiter and then filter results with the words from the list. `$matching` contains all found fragments matching list.

```
$words = file_get_contents('list.txt');
$text = file_get_contents('content.txt');

$elements = explode('DimensionName', $text); // trick
$words = explode(' ', $words); // words list

// leverage native PHP function
$matching = array_reduce($elements, function($result, $item) use($words) {
    if(in_array($item, $words)) { $result[] = $item; }
    return $result;
    }, array());

var_dump($matching);
```

**UPDATE**

`array_reduce()` is a neat function, but I totally forgot about a way simpler solution:

```
$matching = array_intersect($words, $elements);
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/array_intersect):

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

So `$matching` will contain all elements from `$words` array that are present in `$elements`. This is the simplest and possibly the best solution here.

Comment: I think that you'll like my updated answer better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Explode your word list, then loop over it:

```
$word = file_get_contents('list.txt');
$content = file_get_contents('fleetyfleet.txt');
$found_dimensions = array(); // our array
$word_array = explode(' ', $word); // explode the list
foreach($word_array as $one_word) { // loop over it
    $str = 'DimensionName'.$one_word; // what are we looking for?
    if(strstr($content, $str) !== false) { // look for it!
        echo "Found $one_word<br/>"; // Just for demonstration purposes
        $found_dimensions[] = $one_word; // add to the array
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant get it to work properly

   <?php


$word = file('http://www.pixelmon-server-list.com/list.txt');
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.pixelmon-server-list.com/fleetyfleet.txt');
$found_dimensions = array(); // our array
$word_array = explode(' ', $word); // explode the list
foreach($word_array as $one_word) { // loop over it
    $str = 'DimensionName'.$one_word; // what are we looking for?
    if(strstr($content, $str) !== false) { // look for it!
        echo $one_word; // Just for demonstration purposes
        $found_dimensions[] = $one_word; // add to the array
    }
}

 ?>

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working? If `pixelmon-server-list.com` refers to a remote server, you need to add `http://` in front of each time you use it.

Comment: the http is there on mine it just removed when i posted it but its not echoing the results because i know it should find some but none is echoing

Comment: This works fine for me based on the info in the question. What's the separator between words in list.txt?

Comment: I had a typo; `file` in the first line should have been `file_get_contents`.

Comment: i should have seen that one but its still not outputting any results but i know based on the two files some results should be found

Comment: Very strange. It works perfectly when I test it (but I'm only using the test data above; I can't test the data at `http://www.pixelmon-server-list.com/fleetyfleet.txt` right now).

Comment: oh well here is all my code i have if you wanna peek http://pastebin.com/7hWDUG1b

Comment: Ah, you have special characters of some sort in your data. It looks like possibly multi-byte characters in some cases. So, yeah, in that case `strstr` won't work predictably.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted..I loop through each word in `list.txt`, and then use a `preg_match()` to see if that dimension is in `fleetyfleet.txt` (you don't need a regex for my example, but I left it in case your example is more complicated).  If it matches, then I add the match to your array of `$dimensions`.

```
<?php
$dimensions = array();

$content = 'DimensionNameGreenrandomjunktextextcstuffidonwantDimensionNameBluemoreeecrapidontwannaseeeDimensionNameYellowDimensionNameGrayrandomcrapDimensionNameRed';
$list = 'Green Blue Yellow';

foreach(explode(' ', $list) as $word) {
    if(preg_match('/DimensionName' . trim($word) . '/', $content, $matches) {
        $dimensions[] = reset($matches);
    }
}

var_dump($dimensions);
// array(3) {
//     [0]=> string(18) "DimensionNameGreen"
//     [1]=> string(17) "DimensionNameBlue"
//     [2]=> string(19) "DimensionNameYellow"
// }
```